# Qt: Create a search text edit like in many IDEs

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt6

Many IDEs have a extended search text input that offers some options like case sensitivity or regular expressions. Here is the search input from Qt Creator as example:

[image: Search box from Qt Creator]

Is it possible to use this as a widget in my Qt application or how can I create my own one?

Comment: Do you need this feature/widget only for QTextEdit/QPlaintextEdit?

Answer (score 0):

you can use QRegularExpression class

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html

Instantiate an object of this type and use the qstring from a text input widget in the setPattern() function

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#setPattern

Then you can use the match function:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#match